# Apache Spark- Writing parquet with snappy compression errors

Tags: pyspark, compression, parquet, snappy

**Using

1. Spark v3.0.2
2. JAR File - snappy-java-1.1.8.2
3. HADOOP=3.2.2
4. JAVA - java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64**

> Executing : With and without compression key value (default is 'snappy').

```py
df.write.option("compression", "snappy").mode("overwrite").partitionBy(part_labels).parquet(output_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the [pyspark API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet) is slightly different from the [Java/Scala API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#parquet-java.lang.String-). Try this:

```
df.write.parquet(output_path, mode="overwrite", partitionBy=part_labels, compression="snappy")
```

Comment: this suggestion did not work, I think there is a problem with one of the jar files used.

Answer (score 1):

default compression for parquet is snappy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).